# How to run batch file using Runas command from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is our batch file which we have this code but its not running the run.bat file.
Giving Error :
**is not recognized as internal or external command**

```
@echo off
SET Identity=%userdomain%\%username%
CALL :ICACLS "%Identity%"
SET mypath=%~dp0
echo %mypath:~0,-1%
runas /noprofile /user:%Identity% "cmd /K %mypath%\run.bat"
```

Comment: it works, is run.bat in the same directory as the original script?

Comment: also, you set mypath to the current dir, why? you could just call `.\run.bat` seeing as both are in the same dir.

Comment: yes its in the same directory

Comment: try the code in the answer I am about to post.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard it won't run if i remove the %mypath%

Comment: what is the exact error? does it state `run.bat is not recognised as internal....`

Comment: error : is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: so where does that word `error` come from? If I run the exact code you added in the test it works, can you post `run.bat` batch content?

Comment: also, let's see if that script actually finds the run.bat. just `rem` out the runas part and then add `type %mypath%\run.bat` as a line and see if it prints the content of run.bat to the screen

Comment: You are stipulating `/noprofile` but without seeing the content of `run.bat` we have no idea whether that is causing something to malfunction, _(you are already using the default,`%username%`, which suggests that using the default profile would be a safer option)_. Additionally, we have no idea of the posted script content which runs between `CALL :ICACLS %Identity%` until it returns just before `SET mypath=%~dp0`, _(this shouldn't be an issue if the value of `%Identity%` cannot change within that code)_.

Comment: How do you know the error isn't coming from inside run.bat?

Comment: i have run the bat file using call statement, and given the administrator rights to run.bat so it worked.. please remove the down votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Echo Soft
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
 if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' 
 (
 echo Requesting administrative privileges...
 goto UACPrompt
 ) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
 echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
 echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
 exit /B

:gotAdmin
 if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
 pushd "%CD%"
 CD /D "%~dp0"
 ::your code goes here which needs to be run with admin rights::
```